# NullPointerException when calling method in Mockito test

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm working on setting up jUnit tests with Mockito for a project. I'm having trouble when calling a method in the System Under Test (DrawingService). Mocks include a Drawing and an IDrawingRepository.

I'm new to TDD, unit testing, and mocking in general, so maybe I'm making some noob mistake? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Here's the test class:**

```
public class DrawingServiceTest {

    private DrawingService drawingService;
    private Drawing drawing;
    private IDrawingRepository repository;
    private String drawingName;

    @Before // Executed before each @Test
    public void setUp(){
        drawingService = new DrawingService();
        drawing = mock(Drawing.class);
        repository = mock(IDrawingRepository.class);
    }

    @After // Executed after each @Test
    public void tearDown(){
        //clean up code
    }

    @Test
    public void getDrawingTest() throws DrawingNotFoundException{
        drawingName = "A drawing name that exists";

        System.out.println("drawing name is: " + drawingName);
        when(repository.findByName(drawingName)).thenReturn(drawing);

        System.out.println("calling DrawingService.getDrawing(" + drawingName +")");
        drawingService.getDrawing(drawingName); // The test doesn't continue past this line

        System.out.println("verifying repository.findByName(" + drawingName +") is called");
        verify(repository).findByName(drawingName);

    }
```

**Here's the System Under Test:**

```
@Service ("iDrawingService")
public class DrawingService implements IDrawingService {

    @Autowired
    private IDrawingRepository repository;  

    public List<Drawing> getDrawings() {
        return (List<Drawing>) repository.findAll();
    }

    public Drawing getDrawing(String strName) throws DrawingNotFoundException{
        Drawing drawing = repository.findByName(strName); //this line throws the NullPointerException
        if(drawing == null){
            throw new DrawingNotFoundException("No drawing found for name " + strName);
        }
        return drawing;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

In prod, your class will have IDrawingRepository wired by spring. This is not the case with your test (unit test). You will need to hook it up manually. Your options are:

1. Make it as constructor injected
2. Expose a setter for IDrawingRepository

I personally would go with constructor injection, as it is required by your class to work properly. Your class can be tested easily too.

Comment: Thanks for catching that! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `@before` and `@After` in your test, you can simply annotate your subject with `@InjectMocks` and all of your mocked objects with `@Mock`.

With `@InjectMocks` you don't even need getters and setters on the subject. In your tests you never tie `repository` to the subject.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class DrawingServiceTest {

     @InjectMocks private DrawingService drawingService;
     @Mock private Drawing drawing;
     @Mock private IDrawingRepository repository;
     private String drawingName;
```

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful, solved my problem, and simplified the class.

Comment: Happy to help. Go ahead and mark this answer as correct :)